# Why $\lim_{x\to \infty }Mf(x)=0$ where $Mf$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

Tags: measure-theory

In a course it is written that since $Mf(x)$ decay to zero at infinity, the measure or $\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid\left|Mf(x)\right|>\lambda\right\}$ is finite. I was looking for such a result on the Internet but I didn't find anything. Do you have any justification of this ? I recall that $$Mf(x)=\sup_{B\ni x}\frac{1}{\left|B\right|}\int_B \left|f\right|.$$

Comment: That $Mf(x) \to 0$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ is simply incorrect. You can make $f$ blow up infinitely many times for a counterexample. But that $m\{Mf>\lambda\} \leq 3^k\lambda^{-1}\|f\|_1$ for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is a standard result, proved using the Vitali covering lemma.